# How do I know if a button was already clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

In JavaScript, when a user clicks a button, how do I know if it's the same button that he clicked the last time?
For example, if a user clicks a "play" button, and a stop button a few seconds after, how can I know that he clicked the play button before the stop button?

Comment: you can store in a variable some reference to each button

Comment: But not the whole page is in javascript! the moment the javascript code finishes executing, the variable will be deleted and I won't be able to keep track of which buttons were clicked.

Comment: Then you should clarify that on the question, don't you agree?

Comment: What do you mean by "the moment the javascript code finishes executing, the variable will be deleted and I won't be able to keep track of which buttons were clicked."?  That's not true at all.  As long as the page doesn't reload, global variables persist.  Are you saying that when you click the "play" button the page reloads?

Comment: Yeah sorry I was a bit unclear but my question was answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain a global reference to the button that was clicked in click event handler of appropriate button and compare it in subsequent runs.
Sample Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prevButton = null;
    .
    .
    .
    .
    function play(el)
    {
        if(el == prevButton) //Check if User has clicked the same button
        {
            //Add your code here
        }
        else
        {
        }
        prevButton = el;
    }

    .
    .
    .
    function stop(el)
    {
        if(el == prevButton) //Check if User has clicked the same button
        {
            //Add your code here    
        }
        else
        {
        }
        prevButton = el;
    }
    .
    .
    .
</script>
<input type="button" value="Play" onClick="play(this)"/>
<input type="button" value="Stop" onClick="stop(this)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var lastButton;

<input type="button" onclick="function(lastButton = this){}" />
```

Comment: I can't do that, my button is in HTML.

Comment: @MisterSir, yes you can `<input type="button" onclick=function(){lastButton = this;}"`

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery library for the javascript you can use [toggle event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) :

In the html code

```
<input type="button" id="mybutton">
```

And in the javascript

```
$('#mybutton').toggle(function() {
    //here play function
}, function() {
    //here stop function
});
```

And you can [add](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [remove](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) css to the button so it can appear as a play or stop one.

Answer (score 0):

Have a global variable name `playClicked`, and set it to true when the Play button is clicked.  You can then check this in the event handler for the Stop button click event.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could save the button last pressed into a variable.   Or you could have some kind of state (playing, stopped, paused, fast-forwarding, etc.) and buttons can behave differently based on the state.

Answer (score 0):

Place an onclick event on the play button that sets a global flag which you can check when the user clicks on the stop button.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array, and, on the function that handles a click on the button, you could append the id of the button clicked to the array.

To get the button clicked before, you would simply access the second to last item in the array.